# Jira JQL Query - List of issues based on Epic criteria

Tags: jira, jql

For a project, We have multiple epics with "fix Version" as "Aug 2021".

I need a list of all issues underneath these epics.

We have scriptrunner add on available in Jira. Can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using scriptrunner functions.

my jql was:

issuefunction in issuesinEpic("Project = XYZ and fixVersion = 'Aug 2021')

Answer (score 0):

*ScriptRunner*'s JQL functions will definitely help. Note you need to escape quotes inside the subquery argument.

```
issueFunction in issuesInEpics("fixVersion = 'Aug 2021'")
```

or

```
issueFunction in issuesInEpics("fixVersion = \"Aug 2021\"")
```